# Die Signal Handler Invocation Issue

Tags: perl

I am using a signal handler for die to log fatal errors and send mail notification from it. While sending a mail during the script my control is going in this signal handler but it is coming under the errors which are present in eval, the error when printed is "Can't locate object method "tid" via package "threads" at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/XSLoader.pm line 89.". Also when I comment out this signal handler the script works fine.Can someone help me know the cause:

Line 89 XSLoader.pm:

```
return &$xs(@_);
```

XSLoader.pm:

```
# Generated from XSLoader.pm.PL (resolved %Config::Config value)
# This file is unique for every OS

package XSLoader;

$VERSION = "0.21";

#use strict;

package DynaLoader;

# No prizes for guessing why we don't say 'bootstrap DynaLoader;' here.
# NOTE: All dl_*.xs (including dl_none.xs) define a dl_error() XSUB
boot_DynaLoader('DynaLoader') if defined(&boot_DynaLoader) &&
                                !defined(&dl_error);
package XSLoader;

sub load {
    package DynaLoader;

    my ($caller, $modlibname) = caller();
    my $module = $caller;

    if (@_) {
        $module = $_[0];
    } else {
        $_[0] = $module;
    }

    # work with static linking too
    my $boots = "$module\::bootstrap";
    goto &$boots if defined &$boots;

    goto \&XSLoader::bootstrap_inherit unless $module and defined &dl_load_file;

    my @modparts = split(/::/,$module);
    my $modfname = $modparts[-1];

    my $modpname = join('/',@modparts);
    my $c = () = split(/::/,$caller,-1);
    $modlibname =~ s,[\\/][^\\/]+$,, while $c--;    # Q&D basename
    my $file = "$modlibname/auto/$modpname/$modfname.xs\.dll";

#   print STDERR "XSLoader::load for $module ($file)\n" if $dl_debug;

    my $bs = $file;
    $bs =~ s/(\.\w+)?(;\d*)?$/\.bs/; # look for .bs 'beside' the library

    if (-s $bs) { # only read file if it's not empty
#       print STDERR "BS: $bs ($^O, $dlsrc)\n" if $dl_debug;
        eval { do $bs; };
        warn "$bs: $@\n" if $@;
    goto \&XSLoader::bootstrap_inherit;
    }

    goto \&XSLoader::bootstrap_inherit if not -f $file;

    my $bootname = "boot_$module";
    $bootname =~ s/\W/_/g;
    @DynaLoader::dl_require_symbols = ($bootname);

    my $boot_symbol_ref;

    # Many dynamic extension loading problems will appear to come from
    # this section of code: XYZ failed at line 123 of DynaLoader.pm.
    # Often these errors are actually occurring in the initialisation
    # C code of the extension XS file. Perl reports the error as being
    # in this perl code simply because this was the last perl code
    # it executed.

    my $libref = dl_load_file($file, 0) or do { 
        require Carp;
        Carp::croak("Can't load '$file' for module $module: " . dl_error());
    };
    push(@DynaLoader::dl_librefs,$libref);  # record loaded object

    $boot_symbol_ref = dl_find_symbol($libref, $bootname) or do {
        require Carp;
        Carp::croak("Can't find '$bootname' symbol in $file\n");
    };

    push(@DynaLoader::dl_modules, $module); # record loaded module

  boot:
    my $xs = dl_install_xsub($boots, $boot_symbol_ref, $file);

    # See comment block above
    push(@DynaLoader::dl_shared_objects, $file); # record files loaded
    return &$xs(@_);
}

sub bootstrap_inherit {
    require DynaLoader;
    goto \&DynaLoader::bootstrap_inherit;
}

1;


__END__

=head1 NAME

XSLoader - Dynamically load C libraries into Perl code

=head1 VERSION

Version 0.17

=head1 SYNOPSIS

    package YourPackage;
    require XSLoader;

    XSLoader::load();

=head1 DESCRIPTION

This module defines a standard I<simplified> interface to the dynamic
linking mechanisms available on many platforms.  Its primary purpose is
to implement cheap automatic dynamic loading of Perl modules.

For a more complicated interface, see L<DynaLoader>.  Many (most)
features of C<DynaLoader> are not implemented in C<XSLoader>, like for
example the C<dl_load_flags>, not honored by C<XSLoader>.

=head2 Migration from C<DynaLoader>

A typical module using L<DynaLoader|DynaLoader> starts like this:

    package YourPackage;
    require DynaLoader;

    our @ISA = qw( OnePackage OtherPackage DynaLoader );
    our $VERSION = '0.01';
    bootstrap YourPackage $VERSION;

Change this to

    package YourPackage;
    use XSLoader;

    our @ISA = qw( OnePackage OtherPackage );
    our $VERSION = '0.01';
    XSLoader::load 'YourPackage', $VERSION;

In other words: replace C<require DynaLoader> by C<use XSLoader>, remove
C<DynaLoader> from C<@ISA>, change C<bootstrap> by C<XSLoader::load>.  Do not
forget to quote the name of your package on the C<XSLoader::load> line,
and add comma (C<,>) before the arguments (C<$VERSION> above).

Of course, if C<@ISA> contained only C<DynaLoader>, there is no need to have
the C<@ISA> assignment at all; moreover, if instead of C<our> one uses the
more backward-compatible

    use vars qw($VERSION @ISA);

one can remove this reference to C<@ISA> together with the C<@ISA> assignment.

If no C<$VERSION> was specified on the C<bootstrap> line, the last line becomes

    XSLoader::load 'YourPackage';

If the call to C<load> is from C<YourPackage>, then that can be further
simplified to

    XSLoader::load();

as C<load> will use C<caller> to determine the package.

=head2 Backward compatible boilerplate

If you want to have your cake and eat it too, you need a more complicated
boilerplate.

    package YourPackage;
    use vars qw($VERSION @ISA);

    @ISA = qw( OnePackage OtherPackage );
    $VERSION = '0.01';
    eval {
       require XSLoader;
       XSLoader::load('YourPackage', $VERSION);
       1;
    } or do {
       require DynaLoader;
       push @ISA, 'DynaLoader';
       bootstrap YourPackage $VERSION;
    };

The parentheses about C<XSLoader::load()> arguments are needed since we replaced
C<use XSLoader> by C<require>, so the compiler does not know that a function
C<XSLoader::load()> is present.

This boilerplate uses the low-overhead C<XSLoader> if present; if used with
an antique Perl which has no C<XSLoader>, it falls back to using C<DynaLoader>.

=head1 Order of initialization: early load()

I<Skip this section if the XSUB functions are supposed to be called from other
modules only; read it only if you call your XSUBs from the code in your module,
or have a C<BOOT:> section in your XS file (see L<perlxs/"The BOOT: Keyword">).
What is described here is equally applicable to the L<DynaLoader|DynaLoader>
interface.>

A sufficiently complicated module using XS would have both Perl code (defined
in F<YourPackage.pm>) and XS code (defined in F<YourPackage.xs>).  If this
Perl code makes calls into this XS code, and/or this XS code makes calls to
the Perl code, one should be careful with the order of initialization.

The call to C<XSLoader::load()> (or C<bootstrap()>) calls the module's
bootstrap code. For modules build by F<xsubpp> (nearly all modules) this
has three side effects:

=over

=item *

A sanity check is done to ensure that the versions of the F<.pm> and the
(compiled) F<.xs> parts are compatible. If C<$VERSION> was specified, this
is used for the check. If not specified, it defaults to
C<$XS_VERSION // $VERSION> (in the module's namespace)

=item *

the XSUBs are made accessible from Perl

=item *

if a C<BOOT:> section was present in the F<.xs> file, the code there is called.

=back

Consequently, if the code in the F<.pm> file makes calls to these XSUBs, it is
convenient to have XSUBs installed before the Perl code is defined; for
example, this makes prototypes for XSUBs visible to this Perl code.
Alternatively, if the C<BOOT:> section makes calls to Perl functions (or
uses Perl variables) defined in the F<.pm> file, they must be defined prior to
the call to C<XSLoader::load()> (or C<bootstrap()>).

The first situation being much more frequent, it makes sense to rewrite the
boilerplate as

    package YourPackage;
    use XSLoader;
    use vars qw($VERSION @ISA);

    BEGIN {
       @ISA = qw( OnePackage OtherPackage );
       $VERSION = '0.01';

       # Put Perl code used in the BOOT: section here

       XSLoader::load 'YourPackage', $VERSION;
    }

    # Put Perl code making calls into XSUBs here

=head2 The most hairy case

If the interdependence of your C<BOOT:> section and Perl code is
more complicated than this (e.g., the C<BOOT:> section makes calls to Perl
functions which make calls to XSUBs with prototypes), get rid of the C<BOOT:>
section altogether.  Replace it with a function C<onBOOT()>, and call it like
this:

    package YourPackage;
    use XSLoader;
    use vars qw($VERSION @ISA);

    BEGIN {
       @ISA = qw( OnePackage OtherPackage );
       $VERSION = '0.01';
       XSLoader::load 'YourPackage', $VERSION;
    }

    # Put Perl code used in onBOOT() function here; calls to XSUBs are
    # prototype-checked.

    onBOOT;

    # Put Perl initialization code assuming that XS is initialized here


=head1 DIAGNOSTICS

=over

=item C<Can't find '%s' symbol in %s>

B<(F)> The bootstrap symbol could not be found in the extension module.

=item C<Can't load '%s' for module %s: %s>

B<(F)> The loading or initialisation of the extension module failed.
The detailed error follows.

=item C<Undefined symbols present after loading %s: %s>

B<(W)> As the message says, some symbols stay undefined although the
extension module was correctly loaded and initialised. The list of undefined
symbols follows.

=back

=head1 LIMITATIONS

To reduce the overhead as much as possible, only one possible location
is checked to find the extension DLL (this location is where C<make install>
would put the DLL).  If not found, the search for the DLL is transparently
delegated to C<DynaLoader>, which looks for the DLL along the C<@INC> list.

In particular, this is applicable to the structure of C<@INC> used for testing
not-yet-installed extensions.  This means that running uninstalled extensions
may have much more overhead than running the same extensions after
C<make install>.


=head1 KNOWN BUGS

The new simpler way to call C<XSLoader::load()> with no arguments at all
does not work on Perl 5.8.4 and 5.8.5.


=head1 BUGS

Please report any bugs or feature requests via the perlbug(1) utility.


=head1 SEE ALSO

L<DynaLoader>


=head1 AUTHORS

Ilya Zakharevich originally extracted C<XSLoader> from C<DynaLoader>.

CPAN version is currently maintained by SE<eacute>bastien Aperghis-Tramoni
E<lt>sebastien@aperghis.netE<gt>.

Previous maintainer was Michael G Schwern <schwern@pobox.com>.


=head1 COPYRIGHT & LICENSE

Copyright (C) 1990-2011 by Larry Wall and others.

This program is free software; you can redistribute it and/or modify
it under the same terms as Perl itself.

=cut
```

Signal Handler:

```
$SIG{__DIE__} = sub {
    #COMMENT:BELOW IF IS SATISFIED IF DIE INVOKES INSIDE AN EVAL BLOCK
    $Logger->fatal("Inside Signal Handler for Die");
    if($^S) {
        #COMMENT:WE'RE IN AN EVAL {} AND DON'T WANT LOG THIS MESSAGE BUT CATCH IT LATER
        #return;
        $Logger->warn($_[0]);
    }
    elsif(@_){
        $Log::Log4perl::caller_depth++;
        #print "Error logged for die \n";
        $Logger->fatal("ERROR-".@_);
        Error_Mail(@_,$LogFile);
        die @_; # Now terminate really
    }
 };
```

Mail code:

```
$Logger->info("Attachment to be sent in final mail- $attach");

    $sendMsg = MIME::Lite->new(
        From    => $fromAddress,
        To      => $toAddress,
        Cc      => $cc,
        Bcc     => $bcc,
        Subject => $subject,
        Data   => $messageBody,
    );              
    $sendMsg->attach(
        Type     => 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet',
        Path     => $attach,
        Filename => basename($attach),
        Disposition => 'attachment'
    );
    #Sending Mail using the SMTP server
    $sendMsg->send( "smtp", $SmtpIP);
    $Logger->info("Final Mail sent with attachment -".$attach);
```

Output is:

Attachment to be sent in final mail-D:\ABC\AutomationData\ABC\Temp\Output.csv

```
Inside Signal Handler for Die
Can't locate object method "tid" via package "threads" at C:/Strawberry/perl/lib/XSLoader.pm line 89.
D:\ABC\AutomationData\ABC\Temp\Output.csv
```

NOTE: I am using MIME::Lite for forming and sending out mails.

Comment: I used that only to see why the die handler was being invoked. Since there is no error why does it get invoked.

Comment: I have updated the error which I get using $_[0], but no getting what am I missing here?

Comment: Yeah u r correct I misinterpreted it for my script the line reference is for XSLoader.pm instead

Comment: Re "*Also when I comment out this signal handler the script works fine*", Are you implying it doesn't work fine with the signal handler?

Comment: No it means there is no die event called when I remove the handler. The script executes fine.

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: Note that the exception comes from the C code of some Perl module

Answer (score 1):

Having had the same problem, I found out:

> Having to even think about the $^S variable in your exception handlers
>   is simply wrong.  $SIG{**DIE**} as currently implemented invites
>   grievous and difficult to track down errors.

This is what `man perlvar` says. In my case I simply ignored the messages originating from a `require` by iterating over the call stacks like this:

```
y $r;
my @c;
for (my $i = 0; @c = caller($i); ++$i) {
    if ($c[7]) { # is_require
        $r = 1;
        last;
    }
}
```

(Maybe there is a better method to examine the whole call stack)

So if `$r` is set, the message comes from some `require` (or `use`), and I ignore it.

(Before this check, I also checked `$^S` to act on real `die`s only)

Comment: After finding this answer I replaced $SIG{DIE} handler with a different approach proposed in https://perl.apache.org/docs/general/perl_reference/perl_reference.html#Overriding_the_Core_die___Function and the error went away.